# Facebook Ad Preview using JavaScript SDK Not Loading

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Using the [Facebook JavaScript SDK Ad Plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/ad-preview-plugin/v18.0) with Marketing API v18.0 is not actually showing the preview.

I've added the domains the Facebook App settings.

In Firefox console is this message:

```
The loading of “https://www.facebook.com/v18.0/plugins/ad_preview_deprecated.php?ad_account_id=&ad_format=DESKTOP_FEED_STANDARD&adgroup_id=&app_id=XXXXXXXX&channel=https%3A%2F%2Fstaticxx.facebook.com%2Fx%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter%2F%3Fversion%3D46%23cb%3Df3896ccba5ad3e8%26domain%3Dlocal.cloud.pmmimediagroup.com%26is_canvas%3Dfalse%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocal.cloud.pmmimediagroup.com%253A8085%252Ff11adc6e38fea28%26relation%3Dparent.parent&container_width=0&creative=&creative_id=6365635727963&locale=en_US&sdk=joey
```

Note that I redacted the `app_id`

In Chrome, a box displays with the message:

```
Permission Error: Either the object you are trying to access is not visible to you or the action you are trying to take is restricted to certain account types.
```

The API user has the following permissions (set when generating the access token):

- read_insights
- pages_show_list
- ads_management
- ads_read
- pages_manage_ads

Interestingly, in the Facebook Ads Manager, when I preview the ad with that user, it shows:

```
No permission to access this profile
You don't have required permission to access this profile
```

The user has "Manage App" permissions.

So, perhaps the issue is with Facebook?

Here is the code:

```
    <script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
                appId            : '#######',
                xfbml            : true,
                version          : 'v18.0'
            });
        };
    </script>
    <script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"></script>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.adpreview.js#xfbml=1&version=v18.0" nonce="xxxxx"></script>
```

Note that I've redacted the `appId` and `nonce` values.

```
        $html = '';

        if (!empty($previewLink)) {
            $html .= '<a href="' . $previewLink . '" target="_blank">';
        }

        $creativeId = $adsInsightsObject->fb_creative_id;
        if ($this->type === self::CAMPAIGN_TYPE_FACEBOOK && !empty($creativeId)) {
            $html .= '<div class="fb-ad-preview-deprecated" data-creative="" data-ad-account-id="" data-adgroup-id="" data-creative-id="'
                . $creativeId . '" data-ad-format="DESKTOP_FEED_STANDARD"></div>';
        } else {
            $html .= $adsInsightsObject->ad_preview;
        }

        if (!empty($previewLink)) {
            $html .= '</a>';
        }

        return $html;
```

I verified permissions (for both the access token and user) and added the domain to the "App domains" on the Basic App settings.

I've also Googled to no avail.